# Enteprise architect - change the data type in the entire model

Tags: export, database-migration, type-conversion, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to migrate database schema from Sybase to Oracle using Enteprise Architect.

Process is following:

- Import tables from Sybase,
- change schema as necessary (add, remove, rename
  columns, change datatypes...),
- export schema as DDL (create tables, keys, etc. - dump.sql) for Oracle.

But I found out the problem that EA doesn't change datatype "according to platform". For example Sybase is using 'datetime' and I need for Oracle 'timestamp'.

Is there any way how to change one data type over entire model?

Yes, there is the way to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on generated dump.sql and replace these datatypes, but I would like to find some "clean" way in EA (I would like to have corresponding EA schema to resulting Oracle database without importing it backwards).

Thanks very much!

J.

Answer (score 1):

To do such a conversion there is no "clean" way since you are making substantial changes. 2 ways to go anyhow:

1. Using the API: find elements in `t_attribute` with

   ```
   Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT ea_guid FROM t_attribute WHERE stereotype = 'column' AND type='datetime'")
   ```

   Now with the XML result read the according attribute and change the type:

   ```
   attr = Repository.GetAttributeByGUID(<theGuid>)
   attr.type = 'timestamp'
   attr.update()
   ```
2. Just do the above with a direct SQL and a native DB client:

   ```
   UPDATE t_attribute SET type='timestamp' WHERE stereotype = 'column' AND type='datetime'
   ```

The first variant is a bit cleaner, but the 2nd isn't that unsafe. Try either on a copy of your repos first before doing it on production.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

But there is no way how to change it direct in EA? I've found some datatype mapping in EA, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe how you used that datatype mapping?

Comment: I think datatype mapping is used in transformations. There should be somewhere a possibility to transform a database model from one database type to another, but I don't remember how exactly.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Likely so. A transformation will create new elements and is not suitable for changing existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it by exporting project as XML and replacing all needed datatypes to oracles. And imported it to project again.

Thanks to all for your advices.

J.